# What causes 'subscript out of bounds' error in STM topic modeling with missing data?

Tags: r, document, missing-data, topicmodels

I use `stm` for my project. Now I want to show the number of topics. Therefore I take `searchK`. The problem is that I don't understand the error

```
Error in missing$docs[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

The error occurs because the low number of documents I use. Do you know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.